# UISegmentedControl in UINavigationBar disappears when UIViewControllers are not constantly re-instantiated

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I use a UISegmentedControl in the navigation bar to switch between UIViewControllers in my application. However, the UISegmentedControl disappears from the navigation bar after I switch UIViewControls more than once. This only happens when the view controls are not initialized and allocated anew each time the segmented control is pressed. In other words, if I allocate a new UIViewController each time I want to switch views in my app, the expected behavior is observed (eg, UISegmentedControl doesn't disappear). However, this is not a practical solution since I want to save the hidden view's state when the user switches views.

I have [here](https://github.com/aashidham/UISegmentedControl-View-Switching/commit/d416292b48148e49db3674b4bb0c06121a9b43fc#diff-0) a repo of a simple project where this is observed. The project consists of two commits: the older where this problem is observed, and the newer where the problem is 'solved' by constant re-instantiation.

---

More detail about the earlier commit in this repo:

The `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the accountingAppDelegate is where the two view     controllers for the application (RootViewController and CalendarViewController) are both instantiated for the lifetime of the application.

The UISegmentedControl is loaded from a NIB file named SegmentedControl.xib in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

The `toolBarItems` method in the accountingAppDelegate is a convenience method for both viewcontroller's `viewDidAppear` methods, where the `toolbarItems` property of each viewcontroller is set. The UINavigationController looks at this property to assign the items in the navigation toolbar for the current view, from my understanding of [the Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (look up "Displaying a Toolbar").

The only difference with the newer commit is that new instances of RootViewController and CalendarViewController are created each time the user switches from one to the other.

---

My question is: why does constant re-instantiation solve the problem? And more importantly, can I prevent the UISegmentedControl from disappearing *and* preserve the view states of my application?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, this what you are doing:
1. You create an instance of UINavigationController in your appDelegate.
2. You create an instance of RootViewController, which I assume is a custom class of UIViewController.
3. You create an instance of CalendarViewController, -- a custom class of UIViewController.
4. You swap them as rootViewController of the UINavigationController (in bullet 1).
Is it right?

Comment: Yes. this is correct. More specifically, I use the 'setViewControllers:' method of the UINavigationController to indirectly alter the rootViewController property of the UINavigationController. See the indexDidChangeForSegmentedControl method in the accountingappdelegate to see where this happens.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, I don't think this is an appropriate way to do it.
Basically, when you swap the `rootViewController` in `UINavigationController`, you are kind of resetting it! So, you need to init viewControllers again!

My suggestion is that you do the followings:

1. create an instance of `RootViewController` (e.g. `rvc`)
2. create an instance of `CalendarViewController` (e.g. `cvc`)
3. add them to an `NSArray` or `NSMutableArray`
4. create an instance of `UINavigationController` and `initWithRootViewController:` an instance of `UIViewController` (not `rvc` or `cvc`).
5. start with the one you want to show first: e.g.

   pushViewController:rvc animated:NO
6. when you need to swap:

   popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO

   pushViewController:cvc animated:NO

From the UINavigationController point of view, you are popping and pushing viewControllers, from user point of view -- since it is not animated, you are swapping!

If you want to have animation, though. You can't do it this way.
Instead of `UINavigationController` in the first place, you should use a `UIViewController`, add a UIToolBar with the UISegment, and add the view of `cvc` and `rvc` to the `UIViewController`, and when needed, swap them with animation.

and some other suggestions:
This method `[NSArray arrayWithObject:[[CalendarViewController alloc]init]];` is not appropriate. When you pass an object to NSArray, NSArray owns it, so it will hold it. It is better not to init/alloc it, or if you have to, after passing it to `NSArray`, release it.

Comment: I came up with this method based on [this article](http://redartisan.com/2010/5/26/uisegmented-control-view-switching-revisited), so I know that other people are doing this. The article also **specifically warns against a managing view controller enclosing an array of sub-viewcontrollers** in terms of maintainability and code-reuse. I am more interested in precisely why my method doesn't work. What do you mean I am 'kind of resetting' the UINavigationController? Do you mind expanding on this?

Comment: Ok, based on the link you gave me, this is what happens: when you say [self.navigationController setViewControllers:theViewControllers animated:NO]; you are replacing the array of viewControllers in UINavigationControllers with a set of new viewControllers. Here, this array contains only one viewController. By doing this, you place everything, including the titleView, which contains the UISegmentControl. The next line says: incomingViewController.navigationItem.titleView = aSegmentedControl;
 which is putting back or it is better to say add the Segment controller back to the titleView.

Comment: If you look closely at the repo however, you will see that I don't use incomingViewController.navigationItem.titleView to set my UISegmentedControl. This is because I need the Navigation Bar to display other things. I therefore use the toolbarItems property of each view controller that is displayed. This means I can't use the code that you talk about. I need to figure out why my code doesn't work, not to use incomingViewController.navigationItem.titleView = aSegmentedControl.

Comment: I don't see in your sample code, where to add the segment control to the toolbar. But since you are altering everything in UINavController, naturally your segment control goes away every time. You can try one of the three : 1. give the responsibility of putting segment control to rvc and cvc, so whenever they appear, they add the segment control of their own; 2. every time you swap views, add the segment control (similar to the sample code) ; 3. re-instantiate the view every time that it is appearing.